# String input to a class variable in c#

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I tried making a "Student" class that takes the student name and few other things. I have a problem at taking student name as I get an exception when typing the name as input.

In declaration,

```
public class Student
{
     public string studentName;// this one
     public long studentID;
     public int score1;
     ...etc
}
```

then I have inside Main:

```
Student[] student = new Student[N];
// the N is determined by a previous block    of code.
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    check = false; // ignore this one.
    Console.WriteLine("Student {0}", i + 1);
    Console.Write("\t \t Name: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    student[i].studentName = input; 
    // I get an exception at that last line, after typing whatever string.I feel like I've done something horribly wrong.
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What's the exception that you get?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in RandomCoding.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared an Array of Student but you didn't initialized it with Student instances. **i.e** student[i] is null.

After

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
```

You should do

```
student[i] = new Student();
// Rest of the code.
```

Comment: First line: Student[] student = new Student[N];

Comment: No, I mean inside the loop. new Student[N] only reserve the space, it doesn't allocate the space. Add the line i gave you as the first line in the loop, or right before you're using student[i], and it will fix the issue.

Comment: Worked! Basically what happened is that I allocated the N number of Student needed, but I didn't allocate the memory for each one of them right ? thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Student
{
     public string studentName { get;set;}
     public long studentID;
     public int score1;
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         var students = new List<Student>();
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Student {0}", i + 1);
             Console.Write("\t \t Name: ");
             string input = Console.ReadLine();
             students.Add(new Student {studentName = input });
         }                     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Student[] student = new Student[N];
// the N is determined by a previous block    of code.
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    student[i] = new Student();
    check = false; // ignore this one.
    Console.WriteLine("Student {0}", i + 1);
    Console.Write("\t \t Name: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    student[i].studentName = input; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    check = false; // ignore this one.
    Console.WriteLine("Student {0}", i + 1);
    Console.Write("\t \t Name: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
you are missing line below.
     student[i]= new student();
    student[i].studentName = input; 

}
```